# How to create stacked subplots with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to create stacked subplots for my data. I want to have subplots by 'type', 'week' as my x axis, and 'scores' to be stacked.

```
np.random.seed(1234)
test = pd.DataFrame({'week':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                     'score':np.random.uniform(0,1,12),
                    'type': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                     'type2':[3,3,4,4,5,5,3,3,4,4,5,5]})
```

This is what I have now, if I add an argument 'subplot = True'

```
test.groupby(['week','type','type2']).agg('sum').unstack(1).plot(kind='bar', subplots=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you add the code corresponding to the call to `plot`. It will be useful to understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @RomainX I added one of my plots, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, so I have posted an answer tell me if it matches your expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think - but I'm not sure - that it is difficult to combine `stacked` and `subplots` options. So here is a solution producing - I hope - the expected output but may be improved.

```
# Test data
np.random.seed(1234)
test = pd.DataFrame({'week':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                     'score':np.random.uniform(0,1,12),
                    'type': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
                     'type2':[3,3,4,4,5,5,3,3,4,4,5,5]})
grouped = test.groupby(['type','week','type2']).agg('sum')

# Preparing plots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

for group_name, group in grouped.groupby(level=0):
    group.index = group.index.droplevel(0)
    group = group.unstack(1)
    group.columns = group.columns.droplevel()
    group.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, ax=axes[group_name], title='type: ' + str(group_name))
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you can add the stacked=True argument?

```
test.groupby(['week','type','type2']).agg('sum').unstack(1).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: That is close now I want to subplot on 'type2'. So there will be two plots and each plot will have a stacked bar chart.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean 3 subplots for type2=3,4,5 ?